# How to POST to an external IP?

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

**QUESTION:**

I am trying to make a POST request to a Docker instance running on a Compute Engine instance on the Google Cloud Platform.

I get the following error:

`ERROR: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT ExternalIP:Port`

What have I done wrong ?

---

**EDIT:** FireWall Rule was missing to allow tcp:Port Ingress. This fixed the error above.

Now I have the following error:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ExternalIP:Port
```

What is happening is I am trying to connect to the node from my localhost, but the node is configured to only accept requests from itself on purpose (compute engine instance):

https://github.com/clemahieu/raiblocks/wiki/Docker-node

( I tried both with and without "-p 127.0.0.1:7076:7076")

I need to find a way to make a request to the node securely without letting anyone ,but my local machine and the server on which I will host my website, access the node.

I added a Firewall rule to allow access from IP address, but it didn't change anything.

Any ideas ?

---

**CODE:**

```
request.post(
     {
        url: 'https://ExternalIP:Port',
        json: {
             action: '…',
             item1: '…'
        } 
     },
     function (error, response, body) {
         if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
             console.log("BODY: " + body);
         } else {
             console.log("ERROR: " + error);
         }
      }
);
```

Comment: Are you sure that the url is correct? Can you send requests from an other client like Postman? Can you verify that the request is received on GCP?

Comment: Is the error you listed the exact error that you see? The error you are logging is all upper case, but the error you mention in your post has lower case. Just wondering if the error is coming from your POST request or somewhere else.

Comment: @JasonAllshorn Yes, it comes from the POST request, just modified the question to remove potential confusion.

Comment: Do you know if there is any kind of firewall between you and the URL you are posting to?

Comment: @JasonAllshorn Yes, question edited.

Comment: Don't know if this applies in your case. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47087639/5086349

Comment: @JasonAllshorn Implemented this change, did not solve the issue :/

Comment: In order to deduce if this is a firewall issue/GCP connection issue, or something related to the docker container/configuration, have you tried opening other ports on the the firewall and attempting to connect to the VM from your specified IP addresses via other protocols? For example, allowing icmp access and simply pinging the machine from your local machine? It may be possible to rule out firewall/network issues this way and point to configuration issues with the container/Docker or at least provide some additional insight into the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its unclear if you have an actual HTTPS server listening on port 443 (or specified port on the other end).

I also wonder if you can actually use HTTPS with a raw IP address given there is usually a need for a domain + cert involved.

Comment: No, no HTTPS server atm for now. But I also allowed HTTP traffic in the Firewall ? What is missing ?

Comment: The server is listening on port 7076 normally

Comment: How about your keep alive settings? Is the compute engine spun up and able to receive incoming requests? There is mention of it here. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting#communicatewithinternet

Comment: Note sure why the down-vote, but the point was you probably can't access via HTTPS if you haven't configured whats needed for cert-exchange. Try HTTP and see if your server is even reachable.

Comment: @JasonAllshorn Sadly was not the fix :/

Comment: @NikhilKothari  
Please have a look at my edited question, I added a lot more details and context.

Comment: If both your server and client node are on the same GCE network, you likely can just use the VM name instead of the IP and using the internal GCE network without exposing HTTP/HTTPS endpoints and then trying to lock them down. The GCE internal network is only visible to the VMs within the same network.